# How to convert a date format within a SQL Case function

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to convert a date in this query. I've tried multiple places in the script to use the "Convert" function and it still doesn't work. This is an example of the script.

```
SELECT client as ClientName,
CASE
WHEN address.startdate_d is null THEN client.sysadmindata_d ELSE address.startdate_d
END
AS BeginDate
FROM client
```

I tried to use `CONVERT(varchar, echo.er_address.startdate_d, 101)` but it not converting.

Comment: Your use of `convert()` with `101` suggests SQL Server, not MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little unclear but I think you want to wrap the entire case statement in your convert:

```
CONVERT(varchar, CASE WHEN .... END, 101) as BeginDate
```

This will convert the result of the case expression to varchar with the format 101.

Comment: Thanks, Aaron, this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use `COALESCE()` instead of `CASE`:

```
CONVERT(varchar(255), COALESCE(address.startdate_d, client.sysadmindata_d), 101)
```

Also note the length on `varchar()`.  SQL Server has different default lengths in different contexts.  Depending on the default is a bad practice; you should be explicit.

Answer (score -2):

try

```
CONVERT(varchar, echo.er_address.startdate_d, 1)
```

Comment: Could you please explain your answer? Why are you switching the last parameter from 101 to 1? This will help improve your answer.

Comment: The parameter isn't the issue, it the placement of the function that is the problem.

Comment: I made a mistake by correcting the statement, since that sintax correspond to SQL Server NOT MySQL.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.